# qooxdoo item.setImage fails after update to 3.5

Tags: qooxdoo

qooxdoo 3.5 changed qx.ui.mobile.basic.Image#_applySource.
The resourceManager.getImageWidth(source) returns 0, because my source is not inside the qooxdoo source folder.
Any other solution instead of moving the file into the qooxdoo source folder?

```
//I'm using following inside qx.ui.mobile.list.List configureItem.
//../repository/myApp/resources is not the resourceUri as set in LibraryManager.
item.setImage("../repository/myApp/resources/Ellen.png").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is already fixed in branch_3_5_x

You can patch the fixed version inside your local framework, by replacing the content of qx.Mobile image file:

https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/branch_3_5_x/framework/source/class/qx/ui/mobile/basic/Image.js